# Vista Low Battery Life Notification Application

Tags: windows, software-rec, battery-life

I am looking for a program that will minimize all open applications and display a pop-up box saying that the battery has reached a certain level or percentage...

Has anybody heard of such an application?

Comment: not with this particular (and rather unsual) type of 'alarm action', but i'm sure this can be done with autohotkey.

Comment: Autohotkey? Never heard of it... is that an app?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a good battery management tool, I recommend that you use [BatteryCare](http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/index.html).

I am not sure of anything that will minimize all open applications (unless you manually do a macro/script), but you can make it do two custom notification levels.

[image]

For notifications, you can also change the levels that the built in Windows tool will notify you. To get to the section, go to `Control Panel > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    *For notifications, you can also change the levels that the built in Windows tool will notify you. To get to the section, go to Control Panel > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings
    *Click the plus next to battery.
    *Then change the actions,notifications and levels.
    *Then click Apply and/or OK.
    *Close the Window that is left and you are finished!!!
```

Comment: Please use the formatting options offered for answers.